# Word that describes knowing the etiquette for a situation and all related skills

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that combines etiquette and technical skills for a given situation.  Etiquette+ as it were.

Knowing when to curtsey and how.  Knowing how to act at a dance, and how to dance.  Knowing what to call the dominatrix, and how to twist yourself into the pretzel shape she likes.

Comment: A man about town? Versatile?

Comment: The word you seek is _"breeding"_.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for **acumen**.  Its connotation is sometimes closer to having an innate judgment ability for specific circumstances, but it definitely encompasses the meanings of 1) having knowledge and ability and 2) applying specifically to a particular domain